# Exclude product attributes from taxonomy terms loop

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy, terms

As the title suggests, i want to exclude product attributes from the taxonomy terms loop, but each attribute is a unique taxonomy, so i don't know exactly how to exclude all of them programmatically. I'll be grateful if someone knows how to do it.

```
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( 'product', 'objects' );
$exclude = array( 'product_type', 'product_visibility', 'product_cat', 'product_tag', 'product_shipping_class' );

foreach ( $taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
  if ( in_array( $taxonomy->name, $exclude ) ) {
    continue;
  }

  $terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->name,
  ) );

  foreach ($terms as $term) { 
    echo $term->name;
  }   
}
```

Comment: What taxonomies are you trying to get? The one's you've listed there plus attributes are pretty much all of them. Why not just use a whitelist of taxonomies that you *do* want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product attribute taxonomies are prefixed with `pa_`, so you can check the taxonomy name for that prefix and skip it if it exists:

```
if ( substr( $taxonomy->name, 0, 3 ) === 'pa_' ) {
    continue;
}
```